# dynamic inbound endpoint no longer available?

Tags: dynamic, mule, endpoint, inbound

In Mule 2, we used to be able to do the create dynamic inbound endpoint using the following:

```
<quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
  <quartz:job-endpoint
       address="jms://retry.queue?selector=JMSTimestamp%3C%3D%23[System.currentTimeMillis() - 30000]" />
</quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
```

In Mule 3, we are getting an error:

```
The endpoint "jms://retry.queue?selector=JMSTimestamp<=#[System.currentTimeMillis()
- 30000]" is malformed and cannot be parsed... Only Outbound endpoints can be dynamic
```

It sounds like they no longer let the expression evaluator process the "address" before creating the inbound. Am I correct in my interpretation?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, this is not supported anymore in 3.3.

You can use a `<poll>` element to wrap the following script at the beginning of your flow:

```
<scripting:component>
    <scripting:script engine="groovy">
        muleContext.client.request('jms://retry.queue?selector=JMSTimestamp%3C%3D'+(System.currentTimeMillis() - 30000), eventContext.timeout)
    </scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick and definitive answer.